# Ruby On Rails - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

Hy guys... i'm learning Ruby on Rail but i don't know whats going on on this page, this is my error:

> NoMethodError in Contacts#new
>   Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/app/views/contacts/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:
>   undefined method `name' for #

this is my new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
      <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comments %>
          <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'
```

and my contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
  end

end
```

what is going wrong?

Full Error screen 
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cozyi.png)

Comment: It means your `Contact` table don't  have column `name` in database.

Comment: it is my contact table

Comment: it is my contact table class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: can you paste the full error?

Comment: Just added in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your `contact` record doesn't have any `name` attribute, the reason being you don't have it in your db.

To fix it, just run `rake db:migrate`... or if you haven't created a migration yet, you should follow these steps:

```
$ rails g migration AddAttrsToContacts

#db/migrate/add_attrs_to_contacts____.rb
class AddAttrsToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
       add_column :contacts, :name, :string
       add_column :contacts, :email, :string
       add_column :contacts, :comments, :text
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will populate the table with the appropriate columns, and should resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

According to your Image with the error there is no `name` field in contacts please rerun the migration or add those fields.

```
#< contacts id: nil>
```

means contacts has only id so what i guess you did is adding those fields after run this migration which will not invoke the database!

please recreate migration for those fields and remove them from the original file and all should be fine.

don't ever add things to migration file after you run it this can cause big problems when deploy this app from scratch.